# translateX multipletimes to create a static background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have this idea for a background, that I'd like to fill the viewport with.
I have created several static svg files, but they're excessively large for smaller screens (the document size is set at 4000x2200px), and they're not pixel-perfect, which shows at some scales.
Can I just have a cutout (of viewport-high) [diagonal wavy line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf1YR.png) repeat with the translateX enough times to fill the background?

[This is my end-effect with hand-crafted file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gowoj.png).

No animation is required, I think.

Can one for example center the line and translate it on the x-axis to the left & the right at the same time, so it fills the screen?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a repeating background pattern, that can be used in CSS3 instead of manually replicating the image yourself.
In your CSS use:

```
    html { 
        background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gowoj.png) repeat; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

And that should get you an infinite repeating pattern of that squiggly line! If you want it to be less grainy then try making the square image smaller, and replace the URL of the image there with the URL of where your image is (notice how there are no quotes enclosing the URL)

Comment: Thanks, but the line being diagonal and 2200px high, repeats only once once on my background with `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: You need to use a small image so that it can place that image multiple times, if you use a 2000px image then it'll only show that image once